# Android call phone number side menu

Tags: android, call

I'm busy making my first android app and i'm looking to create the following option:
Whenn someone clicks on "Contact us" from "activit_main_drawer.xml"
they will directly call "phone number"

Is there anyone who can help me? :)

This is how the "Button" is called

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_belnu"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_phone_square_solid"
        android:title="BEL nu" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the onclick listener of your button, you can proceed this way, remember to add call permission in the manifest file of your project:

```java
private void makeCall(String phoneNumber){
        try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    return;
                }
                startActivity(intent);
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Whenn i try this i get:
error: integer number too large: 

If i make my phone number in the script 000 i get :
error: incompatible types: missing return value


And if i use this script :

 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "0600000000"));
            startActivity(intent);

it will work butit will not check if the permission is there.

Comment: phoneNumber in the code should be replaced by the phonenumber you need to call. It's a variable.

Comment: I know i changed it to my number, but when i do i get an error

Comment: my snippet is meant to be inside a function that has `void` as return type

Comment: for example `private void callSomeone(String phoneNumber){
...}`

Comment: I edited the answer to make it more transparent